# Error unlocking /dev/sda: Failed to activate device: Invalid argument

Tags: encryption, arch-linux, luks

Occasionally, unlocking my luks encrypted disk errors with this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTzoz.png (posted link because not enough rep for images)
Trying to `mount /dev/sda` returns `mount: /dev/sda: can't find in /etc/fstab.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to tell `mount` where to mount your drive.

**How to mount a drive**

Create a directory that you'll use as the mountpoint for your drive:

```
mkdir /mnt/mydrive
```

Mount your drive with this command:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/mydrive
```

Note: If you don't know your drive's device file, you can run `sudo fdisk -l` or `lsblk`

to identify which one is the partition you're looking for.

Now if you run ls `/mnt/mydrive`, it should list your drive's files.

When you're done, don't forget to unmount your USB drive before removing it from the computer:

```
umount /dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 0):

While Fidle's answer is correct, I would like to propose a solution with fstab.

In `/etc/fstab` you can add static file-systems to your system. Each line contains the following:

`<drive>   <mountpoint>   <filesystem type>   <option>   <dump>   <pass>`

Where most of the time only the first three are important. Under `<option>` you can specify mounting options (as you would using `mount -o`, like read-only and silimar).

`<dump>` would specify the need for the file-system to be dumped and `<pass>` is used to tell `fsck` the order in which file-systems should be checked on reboot. If you put a `0` there it means no check is necessary. Usually your root system has a `1`, meaning it will be checked first, and other file-systems have a value of `2`.

Assuming you have an ext4 file-system on `/dev/sda` that you not want to be dumped or checked, mounted at `/mnt/luks-drive` and no special options, append the following to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda    /mnt/luks-drive    ext4    default    0    0
```

That way a future `mount /dev/sda` will work and use the entry we just set.

**Suggestion:** In your case maybe not needed, but usually I strongly discourage the use of `sdX` names for drives in fstab. Personally, I use the drive's UUID here. To find out your UUIDs:

```
$ ls -lha /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

Simply use `UUID=<your UUID goes here>` instead of `/dev/sda` in `/etc/fstab` then.